# Efficient Way to Work with Job Nos as part of a string

Tags: sql

Using SQL 2008R2

We have several systems that all feed production processes. We get reports from these and need to determine costs by job. The reference nos we get from some of the processes are all varchars that may or may not start with a job no (e.g. production job or non-production jobs). In many cases, we have no control over the format of the reference field.

For example:

"50000_A job" is Job No 50,000
"50001_A different job" is Job No 50,001
"100_TGE" is a non-production job. I only know this because 100 is not a production job no (too short). There will be some that mis-identified by the % is very small so we can live with it

From these I have to figure out what's a production job. I will have a table of valid JobNo's for each year, so 2014 is 50,000 to 85,000, 2015 will be 85,001 to 120,000.

So I have to:

1. Extract left of the underscore
2. Make sure it's an integer
3. Then determine if it's a valid job
4. Then join to another table if it is.

I can do first step with

```
SELECT LEFT(Reference,(CHARINDEX('_',Reference)-1)) -- need to work with 5 and 6 digit nos
```

I have a UDF (performance killer) to test if it really is an int

I guess 3 and 4 can be combined if I use an inner join

So I'm left with

```
Select reference from log 
Inner join jobs on jobs.jobno = IsReallyInt(LEFT(log.Reference,(CHARINDEX('_',log.Reference)-1)))
```

Performance is not going to be stellar

These references span several different 3rd party and internal DB's. In some cases we can add computed columns to isolate the job no in it's own field, but some cannot be modified.

Anyone got a more performant method?

Regards

Mark

Comment: What does the reference table look like?

Comment: Unfortunately, there are several that have different formats (as there are multiple systems). They basically all have times, material codes, operator hours, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your query:

```
Select reference
from log Inner join
     jobs
     on jobs.jobno = IsReallyInt(LEFT(log.Reference, CHARINDEX('_', log.Reference) - 1))
```

`IsReallyInt()` is unnecessary.  You could use `NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%'.  However, I don't think you actually need to extract the integer.  You can just compare directly to the job number.  So, try this:

```
Select reference
from log Inner join
     jobs
     on log.Reference like jobs.jobno + '[_]%'
```

This is also a performance hog.  But, it could possibly take advantage of an index on `log.reference`.